# SSO using joomla and spring

Tags: authentication, joomla, spring-security, openid, single-sign-on

I have 2 websites on the same server: one is made by joomla 3.0 (php), the other by spring framework 3.2 (java).

I would like to have a SSO with minimum code: people can sign-in from one website and they don't need to sign-in for the other.

I thought to openid. But I don't want everybody having an openid to sign-in, so I have to provide my own openid server. Is it a good solution? Is there any better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve the problem by using cookies: both websites are in the same domain. So I coded an external authentication plug-in for Joomla 3.0.

---

Hello I come back after more than 4 years.

In my new architecture, I use JWT now.
So instead of having juste a simple cookie, you can share jwt pass_phrase between servers and store generated jwt in a cookie or in a local_storage.

It's more secure and not dependant of OS/framework/language.

Comment: Can you please give some more details on it?